# Android library project is not getting included in Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, multiple-projects

This query is continuation to my previous question as i did not get answer so i am requesting here. My previous question can be found here ([android - gradle multiproject include and exclude libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209874/android-gradle-multiproject-include-and-exclude-libraries))

With productFlavors, one can avoid include and exclude library projects to main project.
In my case,
ProjectA----- MainProject,
LibA     ---- Library project,
LibB     ---- Library project,
....

LibA classes are used in ProjectA.
LibB classes are not used any where. Its just a library but required as part of ProjectA.apk(Mentioned only in ProjectA manifest file)

After "gradle build", in build/classes/flavor/debug or release/packageName/.. only LibA classes are there. LibB classes are not there in build/classes/.. path and LibB functionality is not working. (Note: The same is working fine with eclipse build)

LibB classes are getting included if by importing LibB classes in ProjectA but LibB is like plug and play type library and not required for all the time.

LibB build.gradle file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {mavenCentral()}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3'}
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'}
            java {srcDir 'src'}
            res {srcDir 'res'}
            assets {srcDir 'assets'}
            resources {srcDir 'src'}
            jni {srcDir 'jni'}
        }
    }
    task configureRelease << {
      proguard.enabled = true
    }
  }
```

How to get include LibB? Please guide me resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - gradle multiproject include and exclude libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209874/android-gradle-multiproject-include-and-exclude-libraries)

Comment: No. Not a duplicate. I am facing problem in including LibB library classes in ProjectA.

Answer (score 3):

You need add dependencies node...

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':LibB')
}

android {
   XXX
}
```