# How do I share dependencies between Android modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android application module (app) and an Android library module (library). Both app and library contain these same dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
}
```

However when I try to add that block to the *project* build.gradle, it complains about not knowing the "compile" DSL.

EDIT: I'm asking about putting this dependencies block in the PROJECT build.gradle, to avoid repeating in each module's build.gradle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - gradle multiproject include and exclude libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209874/android-gradle-multiproject-include-and-exclude-libraries)

Comment: No I'm asking about sharing dependencies between modules to avoid having to repeat them in each module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define shared gradle dependencies in the library module, and if the app module has the library as a dependency, you won't need to specify everything twice. Taking this further, you could create a 'common' module that requires the shared gradle dependencies, and have both the app & library module require the common module.

Answer (score 127):

As of Gradle Plugin version [3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) there is a nicer way to do this. We can control whether each dependency is available for only the current module, or for the current module AND any modules which depend on it. This will allow us to easily share dependencies across modules within a project.

Here's how we used to declare dependencies:

- **compile** 'example.dependency:1.0.0'

Here are the new configurations which should replace compile:

- **implementation** 'example.dependency:1.0.0' --> this dependency is only used within this module
- **api** 'example.dependency:1.0.0' --> this dependency will also be available in any builds that depend on this module

Here's how to do that with the architecture you mentioned in the question. Assuming that we have a module named **'library'** that is consumed by the **'app'** module, we can use the **api** configuration to declare that the dependency should be shared with any module that depends on it.

**library module build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    // dependencies marked 'implementation' will only be available to the current module
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'

    // any dependencies marked 'api' will also be available to app module
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    api 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    api 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
}
```

**app module build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {

    // declare dependency on library module
    implementation project(':library')

    // only need to declare dependencies unique to app 
    implementation 'example.dependency:1.0.0'
}
```

Please see [this guide](https://medium.com/@julesrosser/handling-gradle-dependencies-in-multiple-module-android-projects-9e590c3d20dc) for further information and diagrams.

Comment: Couldn't make it work. Did exactly the same and i'm also using retrofit in library but still. When i import my library module as .aar, after compiling is done successfuly, it crashes on the device with classnotfound exception. Any tips?

Comment: Hi @Jules ...could you please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694352/how-do-i-share-dependencies-that-use-annotationprocessor-between-android-modules

Comment: what about kapt?

Answer (score 11):

The dependencies block(closure) needs DependencyHandler as delegate

You need to pass DependencyHandler of each project to shared dependencies in *project* gradle.build.

***project* build.gradle**

```
ext.sharedGroup = {dependencyHandler->
    delegate = dependencyHandler

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
}
```

***app* build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    sharedGroup dependencies
}
```

ref. https://github.com/b1uec0in/DependencyVersionResolver

(see 2. Using default dependency group.
This sample explains many other tips for sharing library version, sdk versions ... for large project that have many modules.)

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this where the *project* build.gradle will specify the dependencies needed as variable names then in the *app* build.gradle files you just need to include the variable names.  This is very useful when you have many modules and don't want to edit everyone when a version number changes!

***project* build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = '7.5.0'
        supportLibVersion = '22.2.0'
    }
... (the rest of your repositories/dependency info here) ...
}

ext {
    minSdkVersion=16
    targetSdkVersion=21
    buildToolsVersion='22.0.1'
    compileSdkVersion=21

    //Android Dependencies
    supportV4 = 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + supportLibVersion
    supportAnnotations = 'com.android.support:support-annotations:' + supportLibVersion
    recyclerView = 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + supportLibVersion
    cardView = 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + supportLibVersion
    palette = 'com.android.support:palette-v7:' + supportLibVersion
    appCompat = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + supportLibVersion
    multidex = 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    appCompat = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + supportLibVersion
    supportDesign = 'com.android.support:design:' + supportLibVersion
    playServicesAnalytics = 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:' + googlePlayServicesVersion
}
```

***app* build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
   compile rootProject.ext.supportV4
    compile rootProject.ext.appCompat
    compile rootProject.ext.supportAnnotations
    compile rootProject.ext.recyclerView
    compile rootProject.ext.cardView
    compile rootProject.ext.palette
    compile rootProject.ext.appCompat
    compile rootProject.ext.multidex
    compile rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    compile rootProject.ext.playServicesAnalytics

}
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: This is better approach to use dependencies across all modules of Android project

Comment: how do you handle transitive options ?

Answer (score 1):

### Share libraries using ext block in the root project module

> This is an easy way to use the library across all modules in the
> android project

**Please follow these steps:**

1. Add ext block (it is used to define extra properties for the project) in root project gradle file
2. Add common libraries in with variable name in ext block
   e.g name = [
   libraries without implementation keyword
   ]
3. Used this ext block in module level using implementation and variable name
   e.g implementation variable_name

See below code for complete implementation

**build.gradle :project**

```
buildscript {
... (the rest of your repositories here) ...
}

ext { **// ext block start here**




appModuleLibraries = [
            commonLibraries,
            /*Projects*/
            project(':hco-cutout'),
            project(':utils')

    ]

commonLibraries = [
        /*Android Libs*/
        'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0',
        'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1',
        'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0',
        'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3',
        /*Gesture viw for image zooming */
        'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.5.2',


]
cutoutModulleLibraries = [
        commonLibraries,
        project(':utils'),
        // Selfie segmentation
        'com.google.mlkit:segmentation-selfie:16.0.0-beta4',

        /*checker board drawable*/
        'com.github.duanhong169:checkerboarddrawable:1.0.2',
]
} **// ext block end here**
```

**build.gradle :app**

```
      dependencies {
    
      /*App Module Libraries in root project gradle*/

        implementation appModuleLibraries
    }
```

**build.gradle :cutout**

```
 dependencies {
    /*cutout Module Libraries in root project gradle*/

    implementation cutoutModulleLibraries

    implementation project(':utils')

}
```

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Based on @SMKS answer, I would prefer this solution for transitive option capability and simplicity

***project build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
... (the rest of your repositories/dependency info here) ...
}

ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = '7.5.0'
        supportLibVersion = '22.2.0'
}
```

***app build.gradle file***

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + supportLibVersion
    compile ' com.android.support:support-annotations:' + supportLibVersion
    compile = 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + supportLibVersion {
        transitive = true // do not know if this make sens/interest just for example
    }
   ...
}
```