# How to access dependencies of dependencies with gradle in android studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Am I missing something here? I'm using android studio. I will be developing two apps with a shared code base, so I made three modules in my android studio project. One module is a library project with shared code, and the other two are apps. This is an app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "omitted"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

this is the shared module's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My expectation is that my app should have access to the dependencies of the shared code module (for example `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`). Is this wrong? I cannot find any way to pass on these dependencies to the dependent app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443958/7804719 Check this

Comment: @JaydipKalkani oh my god I can't believe I missed this with all of my Googling. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use `api` instead of `implementation` in my shared module's `'build.gradle` dependencies.

ie. I want `api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

Courtesey of Jaydip Kalani's comment and [How do I share dependencies between Android modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841259/how-do-i-share-dependencies-between-android-modules/48443958#48443958)

However as far as I'm aware there is no such thing as `testApi` to replace `testImplementation`.